# subtract standard deviation from the max value

Tags: numpy

I have an array `a` (shape(5,4))

```
[[ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

I want to subtract the standard deviation from the max value(15) so the final result will be

```
[[ 8  9 10 11]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 12.23413666]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 8.,  9., 10., 11.,], [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.], [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.], [12., 13., 14., 15.], [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
max_index = np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
a[max_index] -= a.std()
print(a)
```

For max_index, you have to use the unrave_index function because numpy's argmax returns the index from the flattened array. After that, you simply substract the standard deviation from the value at max_index.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
 [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
 [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14, 15],
 [ 8,  9, 10, 11]], dtype=float)

# get indices of maximum values
indices = np.where(a == a.max())

# subtract std from values
a[indices] -= a.std()

print(a)
```